# Global existence theorems

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

Consider the following initial value problem:

$$
\begin{cases}
y'(t) = f(t, y(t)) \\
y(t_0) = y_0
\end{cases}
$$

where $f$ is a continuous and locally $y$-Lipschitz function defined on a vertical strip $]a,b[ \times \Bbb R$ such that $t_0 \in ]a,b[$.

Now, I know that by Cauchy's Existence and Uniqueness Theorem there exists a local solution in a neighborhood of the initial condition $(t_0, y_0)$. Moreover, I also know that if $f$ is sub-linear (i.e.: $\forall (t.y) \in ]a,b[ \times \Bbb R, |f(t,y)| \leq L_1|y| + L_2$ for some non negative constants $L_1,L_2$) then the solution is global in that we can use the bound given by Peano to extend the solution up to $]a,b[$.

My questions are thus the following: **what can we say when $f$ is sub-linear but it is not defined on a vertical strip?** and **what can we say when $f$ is sub-linear but not locally $y$-Lipschitz and hence we may only invoke Peano's Existence Theorem?**

I tried proving the existence of a global solution in the first case but I couldn't do it given that now I have to be careful that the bound on the solution is also compatible with the domain of $f$. Moreover I don't even know where to start in the second case since I can not use the uniqueness of a solution to past two solutions together and get a new continuously differentiable solution.

---

As always any comment or answer is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: What do you mean by “$f$ is not defined on a vertical strip”? In the second case, by Peano (if I’m not mistaken), $y$ always extends to a maximal solution defined on an open interval $(c,d)$, and $y$ can’t converge towards a limit at $d$ (or $c$). Let’s show that $y$ is global, ie $(c,d)=(a,b)$. Assume wlog $b>d$. The bound $|y’| \leq C(|y|+1)$ implies that $y$ can’t be bounded near $d$. Now let $Y(t)=\int_{t_0}^t{|y’(t)|dt}$, then $Y$ is nondecreasing non-negative and up to raising $C$, $Y’ \leq C(Y+1)$ and $Y \geq |y|-C$. By Gronwall we can bound $Y(d^{-})$, hence a contradiction.

Comment: @Aphelli I mean, e.g., that $f$ is defined on $]a,b[ \times ]c,d[$. Also, why can’t $y$ be bounded near $d$ in your comment?

Comment: If $y$ is bounded near $d$, then $y’$ is bounded near $d$, so $y$ has a limit at $d^{-}$ (thus $y’$ as well, and it’s the “correct one”). By Peano you can find a solution starting at $d$ with value $y(d^-)$ and glue it to $y$.